# formula and a table in align environment

Tags: align

I need to type formula and table in an align environment like
[image]
but I only could prepare

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
&$ \left(\frac{1}{2} \, m'\right| J_x \left| \frac{1}{2} \, m \right) $&
\\ && \\
\diagbox{$ m' $}{$ m $}& $ +\frac{1}{2} $ & $ -\frac{1}{2} $ \\ [1.5 em]
$ +\frac{1}{2} $ & 0 & $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ \\ [1.5 em]
$ -\frac{1}{2} $ & $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & 0  \\ [1.5 em]
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{c c c}
&$ \left(\frac{1}{2} \, m'\right| J_y \left| \frac{1}{2} \, m \right) $&
\\ && \\
\diagbox{$ m' $}{$ m $}& $ +\frac{1}{2} $ & $ -\frac{1}{2} $ \\ [1.5 em]
$ +\frac{1}{2} $ & 0 & $-i\frac{\hbar}{2}$ \\ [1.5 em]
$ -\frac{1}{2} $ & $i\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & 0  \\ [1.5 em]
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{c c c}
&$ \left(\frac{1}{2} \, m'\right| J_z \left| \frac{1}{2} \, m \right) $&
\\ && \\
\diagbox{$ m' $}{$ m $}& $ +\frac{1}{2} $ & $ -\frac{1}{2} $ \\ [1.5 em]
$ +\frac{1}{2} $ & $\frac{\hbar}{2}$ & 0  \\ [1.5 em]
$ -\frac{1}{2} $ &  0 & $-\frac{\hbar}{2}$  \\ [1.5 em]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which is not the same as what I  want. How can I figure it out?

Many thanks

Comment: Consider Ti*k*Z...

Comment: Please explain your suggestion with a code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Ti*k*Z code for the first diagram (and you can draw the rest I think).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes,nodes={
    minimum height=0.8cm,minimum width=1.5cm,anchor=center}] (x) {
& +\frac12 & -\frac12\\
+\frac12 & 0 & \frac\hbar2\\
-\frac12 & \frac\hbar2 & 0\\};
\draw (x-2-3.north east) -| (x-3-2.south west);
\draw (x-2-2.north west) -- ++ (-1,2/3)
    node[midway,above right,inner sep=2pt] {$m$} 
    node[midway,below left,inner sep=0pt] {$m'$};
\path (x-1-2.north) node[above=1ex] {$(\frac12m'\mid J_x\mid\frac12m)$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]